# Minimum enclosing rectangle with given orientation

Tags: opencv, image-processing, rectangles, bounding-box

I'm looking for a function that computes the minimum area "oriented" rectangle of an object with a given orientation.

The `minAreaRect` function isn't good in this case because, once I compute the orientation of the object, I need to find the MER aligned with it, so to get the height and the width of the object.

[image]

Comment: Can you be more clear? You want a _"minimum oriented enclosing rectangle"_, but the function that computes exactly this is not good for you?

Comment: I need a function that computes the MER with a given orientation. I compute the orientation of the object, and i give it as input to the function. I tried to make an example, the redline is the inertial axis: http://imgur.com/a/EQHKq

Comment: Ok it's clearer. The simplest thing to do is, once you have your orientation, you rotate (a portion of) your image (or just the points) so that the orientation is exactly vertical, and then compute the `boundingBox`. If needed, you can create a `RotatedRect` with angle 0 starting from the bbox, and then assign the same angle as your original orientation

Comment: To rotate i should use       wrapAffine      ?

Comment: You can use `getRotationMatrix2D` to get the rotation matrix. If you want to rotate the image then use `warpAffine`. If you have already the points on the contour, you can rotate just the points using `transform`

Comment: The resulting rectangle in both the cases have the same area right?

Comment: Highly recommend you check this: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34767-a-suite-of-minimal-bounding-objects